# How to handle error during file transformation

Tags: spring-integration

When a large file is uploaded to a polled directory, and is attempted to be unzipped, an error takes place, because the file is not yet complete.

How to make a **retry** of polling after some time?

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1500"))
public FileReadingMessageSource poll() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setScanEachPoll(true);
    source.setDirectory(new File(pathConfig.getIncomingDirPath()));
    source.setUseWatchService(true);
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.zip"));
    return source;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "unzipChannel")
public Message convert(Message<File> fileMessage) {
    UnZipTransformer unzipTransformer = new UnZipTransformer();
    unzipTransformer.setZipResultType(ZipResultType.FILE);
    unzipTransformer.setWorkDirectory(new File(pathConfig.getWorkDirPath()));
    unzipTransformer.setDeleteFiles(false);
    unzipTransformer.afterPropertiesSet();
    File file = fileMessage.getPayload();
    return unzipTransformer.transform(fileMessage);
}
```

**EDIT** - i can't get `LastModifiedFileListFilter` to work with large files. It works fine with small ones; and when I upload a large one, it does not react any more.

**EDIT2**
Thanks to advice from **Artem and Gary**, here is the solution that worked for me.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1500"))
public FileReadingMessageSource poll() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setScanEachPoll(true);
    source.setDirectory(new File(pathConfig.getIncomingDirPath()));
    source.setUseWatchService(true);
    FileListFilter simplePatternFileListFilter = new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.zip");
    source.setFilter(new ChainFileListFilter<>().addFilter(simplePatternFileListFilter));
    return source;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "unzipChannel", 
  adviceChain = "retryOnIncompleteData")
public Message convertZip(Message<File> fileMessage) {
    UnZipTransformer unzipTransformer = new UnZipTransformer();
    unzipTransformer.setZipResultType(ZipResultType.FILE);
    unzipTransformer.setWorkDirectory(new File(pathConfig.getWorkDirPath()));
    unzipTransformer.setDeleteFiles(false);
    unzipTransformer.afterPropertiesSet();
    return unzipTransformer.transform(fileMessage);
}

@Bean
public Advice retryOnIncompleteData() {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    RetryTemplate template = createRetryTemplate();
    advice.setRetryTemplate(template);
    return advice;
}

private RetryTemplate createRetryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    policy.setMaxAttempts(15);
    template.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(25000l);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually since you use only `SimplePatternFileListFilter`, any your files are going to be retried on each poll interval.

To avoid re-fetching the same file over and over (if you don't delete it in the end of the process), we recommend to use `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` as a part of the `CompositeFileListFilter`.

In case of error like yours you can use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to call `onFailureExpression` to `ResettableFileListFilter.remove()` implementation of the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

On the other hand instead of `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` you can consider to use `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` to retry an `unzipping` process: you don't need to re-fetch file from the localsystem.

These AOP advices you should apply to the `@Transformer`.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

BTW, I would say `fixedRate` is not good for large files. Especially when you have errors like this. The `fixedDelay` would be better. See their JavaDocs for more information.

Comment: It's generally better to upload the file with a different name and then rename it after the transfer is complete (that's what the spring integration adapters do, for example). Another technique is to send a second file when the transfer is complete and use a filter to ignore files that don't have the marker file present. Another option that might work for you is the `LastModifiedFileListFilter` as long as the OS updates the file modified date while the transfer is happening. Only accept the file if it hasn't been modified for some time.

Comment: Thanks alot Artem and Gary!

Comment: Gary, `LastModifiedFileListFilter` did not work for large files. I updated my code snippet.

Artem, I am slightly confused with how to call `AcceptOnceFileListFilter.remove()`, using a SpEL expression.

Comment: `@acceptOnceFileListFilter.remove(payload)`, where that `payload` is a polled `File`. Exactly what you accept in the `@Transformer`